# MySQL update based on PHP array with lowest value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array named $priority_array.

Some sample outputs are:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 6
        [ask_for_review] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 5
        [ask_for_review] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 7
        [ask_for_review] => 3
    )

)
```

And another...

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 7
        [ask_for_review] => 3
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 9
        [ask_for_review] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 11
        [ask_for_review] => 2
    )

)
```

I want to update a row that is based on the first lowest value of ask_for_review that is encountered in the array.

In the first example, ID 5 would be updated. The other IDs would be ignored.
In the second example, ID 9 would be updated. The other IDs would be ignored.

The update would be something similar to:

```
$query = "UPDATE tasks SET priority='1' WHERE ..."
```

I don't know what to do for the where clause.  How can I select the lowest value from a PHP array and put that into a mysql query?

## ADDED

Thank you @fedeisas  for your help below.

Is the best way to use the function in a query like this:

$search_id = get_min_row($priority_array);
$query = "UPDATE tasks SET priority='1' WHERE ID = $search_id;";

Or is there a better method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably do this using directly SQL, but I don't know the structure of your tables, so I'm going to assume you want to find the minimum using PHP.

This is one possible approach:

```
<?php 

$list_1 = [
    ['ID' => 6, 'ask_for_review' => 2],
    ['ID' => 5, 'ask_for_review' => 1],
    ['ID' => 7, 'ask_for_review' => 3]
];

$list_2 = [
    ['ID' => 7, 'ask_for_review' => 3],
    ['ID' => 9, 'ask_for_review' => 2],
    ['ID' => 11, 'ask_for_review' => 2]
];

function get_min_row($list) {
    $reviews = array_map(
        function ($row) {
            return $row['ask_for_review'];
        },
        $list
    );
    $row_key = array_search(min($reviews), $reviews);

    return $list[$row_key]['ID'];
}

var_dump(get_min_row($list_1)); // int(5)
var_dump(get_min_row($list_2)); // int(9)
```